# Pattern matching on Orderless functions

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, attributes

I'm trying the following pattern matching command:

```
ReplaceList[Hold[b + a], Hold[x___ + y___] -> {{x}, {y}}]
```

And Mathematica returns:

```
{{{}, {b, a}}, {{b}, {a}}, {{a}, {b}}, {{b, a}, {}}}
```

Can someone help me to understand why `{{}, {a, b}}` and `{{a, b}, {}}` don't belong to the solution?

As `Plus` head has `Orderless` attribute, the pattern matcher should try all permutations (and this explains why `{{}, {a, b}}` belongs to the solution). Where am I wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Orderless means `{a, b}` and `{b, a}` are equivalent.  They are (probably) considered identical in pattern matching to reduce combinatorial explosion of cases.

Answer (score 2):

Turning my comment into an answer:

[`Orderless`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) means `{a, b}` and `{b, a}` are equivalent. They are (probably) considered identical in pattern matching to reduce combinatorial explosion of cases.  So in terms of [`ReplaceList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceList.html) applying the replacement in "all possible ways",  `{a, b}` and `{b, a}` are considered the same and only one result is returned in the list.